# Изменение элемента в нескольких списках по его индексу в Python

Tags: python, list, for

У меня есть список со списками. Нужно в каждом из подcписков заменить одно значение по индексу на другое значение. Покажу на примере:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

for podlist in list:
    for i in podlist:
        if podlist.index(i) == 0:
            i = 2
print(list)
```

Что я получаю:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Желаемый результат:

```
[[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Извиняюсь что забыл упомянуть, Python

Comment: в чем логика замены? все первые элементы сделать равными 2?

Comment: В вашем случае `i` менять бесполезно - это переменная, в которую попадает значение из списка, но у неё нет обратной связи с этим списком. Значение нужно заменять в самом списке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for podlist in list:
    podlist[0] = 2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, даже стыдно за такую глупую ошибку